# Did the Through The Loop survey complete properly?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I've just tried to fill in the Through The Loop survey referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/?cb=1), and it seemed to end very abruptly.

I answered a couple of free-form questions about what I do and don't like, then my age, gender and race, then how many years I've been coding. I clicked Next and was immediately presented with a Cookie permissions box and seemed to be back at the front page of SurveyMonkey. When I pressed back, or if I try to navigate to the survey again, I get a page saying "You have already taken this survey."

Perhaps I finished it, but there was no obvious clue that I had like a "thanks for your views" type of end page. Or maybe I wasn't positive enough in my comments about what I like and so it was automatically binned before I'd even finished? :P

Answer (score 16):

Oh, no, I've just done it again, and it did complete. It's just that the 'Thanks for completing this survey' message is blurred behind the cookies notice, and then disappears when you click to accept the cookies, so I didn't see it first time around.

I'll leave this here because it still seems confusing, but perhaps is just a restriction of Survey Monkey (although I've not been confused by it on other surveys...)